# ¿Cómo puedo comparar un Position<Pair<Element,Integer>> con un Element el en java?

Tags: java

necesito saber cómo puedo comparar si el es igual a los elementos que hay en la lista de posiciones de tipo Position>
Necesito hacer el siguiente método

```
public boolean iguales(Element el) {
}
```

Tengo este constructor que crea una lista de Posiciones usando la clase Pair

```
public MultiSetList() {
    this.loselementos = new NodePositionList<Pair<Element,Integer>>();
    }
```

Y necesito saber si el Element el es igual a todos los elementos de la lista de posiciones, ¿sabría alguien decirme cómo?

Comment: Tu pregunta es algo confusa podrias explicar mas detalladamente que es lo que buscar y mostrar algo de codigo ya que no se  a que te refires con la clases Position o Element

Comment: Si, ya lo edité

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PositionList es una lista de Nodos, podes implementarla con Nodos simplemente enlazados o doblemente enlazados,etc. 
>   Cada Nodo implementa a la interfaz Position, este le brinda el metodo element() a Nodo.

[image: UML Nodo]

> Aca sos cliente de PositionList, asi que no tenes acceso a la estructura interna de la lista por lo que no podes ver a los nodos, pero como Nodo implementa Position, podes moverte con Position, a el mismo solo le podes pedir a element().
>
> Elemplo de Position

```
//DoubleLinkedList le llamo a la implementacion de la interfaz 
//PositionList<E> en tu caso es NodePositionList
PositionList<E> lista = new DoubleLinkedList<E>();
//falta agregar try y catch 
Position<E> pos= lista.first();
//Con esto tengo el primer elemento de la lista que como es 
//generico es E, si la lista es de Integer, voy a tener el primer 
//entero y la lista es de Pair<Element,Integer> voy a tener el primer
//Pair de la lista.
 E elemento = pos.element();
 //esto va a ser verdadero;   
 boolean comparacion = pos.element().equals(elemento);
```

> Las operaciones como next(pos), prev(pos), first() y Last() son metodos de la interfaz PositionList que devuelven Position; 
>   En tu ejemplo tenes que reemplazar a E por Pair y vos queres comparar el Element.
>   Cuando  a la Pisition> le pedis element() te devuelve el Pair, cuando al mismo le pedis getK() te devuelve una variable tipo Element que es la que queres comparar.
>   Ejemplo:

```
 PositionList<Pair<Element,Integer>> listaDePares= new 
 DoubleLinkedList<Pair<Element,Integer>();
 //falta try y catch
 Position<Pair<Element,Integer>> pos = listaDePares.last();
 Pair<Element,Integer> ultimoPar = pos.element();
 Element elementoDelUltimoPar = ultimoPar.getK();
 //para comprar: lo mismo
 boolean elementoDelUltimoPar.equals(elementoDelParametroFromal);
```

Comment: Y a qué inicializarias las variables pos y par??

Comment: ahí lo modifique espero haber respondido tu pregunta, si no hacérmelo saber

Comment: si, gracias! era ese get para acceder al element